# If objects into an array have the same value merge them in one object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter

I have this array of objects. Every object has a unique value label. I would like to compare them by the label value and if the value matches a new object with the unique value should be created.

```js
  var test = [{
          isnewLanguage: "false",
          label: "label1",
          languages: [{
          language: "English",
          questions: [{
          choices: "choices1",
          fields: "false",
          mainText: "MAinText1",
          subText: "SubText1"
        }]
        }],
          numberOfChoices: "5"
        }, {
          isnewLanguage: "false",
          label: "label2",
          languages: [{
          language: "English",
          questions: [{
          choices: "choices2",
          fields: "false",
          mainText: "MAinText2",
          subText: "SubText2"
        }]
        }],
          numberOfChoices: "5"
        }, {
          isnewLanguage: "true",
          label: "label1",
          languages: [{
          language: "Italian",
          questions: [{
          choices: "choicesItalian1",
          fields: "false",
          mainText: "MainTextItalian1",
          subText: "SubTextItalian1"
        }]
        }],
          numberOfChoices: "false"
        }, {
          isnewLanguage: "true",
          label: "label2",
          languages: [{
          language: "Italian",
          questions: [{
          choices: "choicesItalian2",
          fields: "false",
          mainText: "MAinTextItalian2",
          subText: "SubTextItalian2"
        }]
        }],
          numberOfChoices: "false"
        }, {
          isnewLanguage: "true",
          label: "label1",
          languages: [{
          language: "Chinece",
          questions: [{
          choices: "choicesChinece",
          fields: "false",
          mainText: "MainTextChinece1",
          subText: "SubTextChinece1"
        }]
        }],
          numberOfChoices: "false"
        }, {
          isnewLanguage: "true",
          label: "label2",
          languages: [{
          language: "Italian",
          questions: [{
          choices: "choicesItalian2",
          fields: "false",
          mainText: "MAinTextItalian2",
          subText: "SubTextItalian2"
        }]
        }],
          numberOfChoices: "false"
        }]
```

Below is the required structure. Each object with the same label value should be appended to one object with the new languages.

```js
var theRequiredStructure = [{
      isnewLanguage: "true",
      label: "label1",
      languagesTest: [{
      language: "English",
      questions: [{
      choices: "choices1",
      fields: "false",
      mainText: "MAinText1",
      subText: "SubText1"
    }]
    }, {
      language: "Italian",
      questions: [{
      choices: "choicesItalian1",
      fields: "false",
      mainText: "MainTextItalian1",
      subText: "SubTextItalian1"
    }]
    }, {
      language: "Chinece",
      questions: [{
      choices: "choicesChinece",
      fields: "false",
      mainText: "MainTextChinece1",
      subText: "SubTextChinece1"
    }]
    }],
      numberOfChoices: "false"
    },
    {
      isnewLanguage: "true",
      label: "label2",
      languagesTest: [{
      language: "English",
      questions: [{
     choices: "choices2",
      fields: "false",
      mainText: "MAinText2",
      subText: "SubText2"
    }]
    }, {
      language: "Italian",
      questions: [{
      choices: "choicesItalian2",
      fields: "false",
      mainText: "MainTextItalian2",
      subText: "SubTextItalian2"
    }]
    }, {
      language: "Chinece",
      questions: [{
      choices: "choicesChinece2",
      fields: "false",
      mainText: "MainTextChinece2",
      subText: "SubTextChinece2"
    }]
    }],
      numberOfChoices: "false"
    }
```

Here is my work but obviously it works only for the first element. How can I achieve the required structure for all elements? I prefer mostly ES5 solutions which is understandable to me. Thanks for taking the time

```js
var test = [{
      isnewLanguage: "false",
      label: "label1",
      languages: [{
      language: "English",
      questions: [{
      choices: "choices1",
      fields: "false",
      mainText: "MAinText1",
      subText: "SubText1"
    }]
    }],
      numberOfChoices: "5"
    }, {
      isnewLanguage: "false",
      label: "label2",
      languages: [{
      language: "English",
      questions: [{
      choices: "choices2",
      fields: "false",
      mainText: "MAinText2",
      subText: "SubText2"
    }]
    }],
      numberOfChoices: "5"
    }, {
      isnewLanguage: "true",
      label: "label1",
      languages: [{
      language: "Italian",
      questions: [{
      choices: "choicesItalian1",
      fields: "false",
      mainText: "MainTextItalian1",
      subText: "SubTextItalian1"
    }]
    }],
      numberOfChoices: "false"
    }, {
      isnewLanguage: "true",
      label: "label2",
      languages: [{
      language: "Italian",
      questions: [{
      choices: "choicesItalian2",
      fields: "false",
      mainText: "MAinTextItalian2",
      subText: "SubTextItalian2"
    }]
    }],
      numberOfChoices: "false"
    }, {
      isnewLanguage: "true",
      label: "label1",
      languages: [{
      language: "Chinece",
      questions: [{
      choices: "choicesChinece",
      fields: "false",
      mainText: "MainTextChinece1",
      subText: "SubTextChinece1"
    }]
    }],
      numberOfChoices: "false"
    }, {
      isnewLanguage: "true",
      label: "label2",
      languages: [{
      language: "Italian",
      questions: [{
      choices: "choicesItalian2",
      fields: "false",
      mainText: "MAinTextItalian2",
      subText: "SubTextItalian2"
    }]
    }],
      numberOfChoices: "false"
    }]

var theLanguagesTest = [];
var obj = {};
for (var i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
  if (test[0].label == test[i].label) {
    obj = test[i]

  }
  for (var j = 0; j < test[i].languages.length; j++) {
    if (test[0].label == test[i].label) {
      theLanguagesTest.push(test[i].languages[j])
      obj.languagesTest = theLanguagesTest
    }
  }
  delete test[i].languages;
  delete test[i].questions;
}




console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this? It's just a draft code, only to show you the logic (one of possible ways). Read comments in the code below

```js
var test = [{
  isnewLanguage: "false",
  label: "label1",
  languages: [{
    language: "English",
    questions: [{
      choices: "choices1",
      fields: "false",
      mainText: "MAinText1",
      subText: "SubText1"
    }]
  }],
  numberOfChoices: "5"
}, {
  isnewLanguage: "false",
  label: "label2",
  languages: [{
    language: "English",
    questions: [{
      choices: "choices2",
      fields: "false",
      mainText: "MAinText2",
      subText: "SubText2"
    }]
  }],
  numberOfChoices: "5"
}, {
  isnewLanguage: "true",
  label: "label1",
  languages: [{
    language: "Italian",
    questions: [{
      choices: "choicesItalian1",
      fields: "false",
      mainText: "MainTextItalian1",
      subText: "SubTextItalian1"
    }]
  }],
  numberOfChoices: "false"
}, {
  isnewLanguage: "true",
  label: "label2",
  languages: [{
    language: "Italian",
    questions: [{
      choices: "choicesItalian2",
      fields: "false",
      mainText: "MAinTextItalian2",
      subText: "SubTextItalian2"
    }]
  }],
  numberOfChoices: "false"
}, {
  isnewLanguage: "true",
  label: "label1",
  languages: [{
    language: "Chinece",
    questions: [{
      choices: "choicesChinece",
      fields: "false",
      mainText: "MainTextChinece1",
      subText: "SubTextChinece1"
    }]
  }],
  numberOfChoices: "false"
}, {
  isnewLanguage: "true",
  label: "label2",
  languages: [{
    language: "Italian",
    questions: [{
      choices: "choicesItalian2",
      fields: "false",
      mainText: "MAinTextItalian2",
      subText: "SubTextItalian2"
    }]
  }],
  numberOfChoices: "false"
}];
        
        
// New array
const result = [];
// Map object to map key -> result array index
const map = {};

// Simple loop     
for(let i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
  // If map contains key with current label
  // then we have it in result array
  if(map[test[i].label] && result[map[test[i].label]] === 0 || result[map[test[i].label]]) {
    // Push same label languages content to results array languageTests subarray
    result[map[test[i].label]].languageTests.push(test[i].languages[0]);
  } else {
    // Else create map record
    map[test[i].label] = Object.keys(map).length;
    // Copy and modify current object
    const item = test[i];
    // Create languageTests sub array
    item.languageTests = [];
    // Copy languages object there
    item.languageTests.push(item.languages[0]);
    // delete languages
    delete item.languages;
    // Push re-formed item to results
    result.push(item);
  }
}

// Log
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort but unfortunately not I do not need this kind of structure.  The objects with the same label should be merged in one obj and the different languages with the same label should be pushed in a new array. Above theRequiredStructture json shows what do I need

Comment: @ioan-dimi check it now, there was little bug

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this also:

```js
var test = [{
    isnewLanguage: "false",
    label: "label1",
    languages: [{
        language: "English",
        questions: [{
            choices: "choices1",
            fields: "false",
            mainText: "MAinText1",
            subText: "SubText1"
        }]
    }],
    numberOfChoices: "5"
}, {
    isnewLanguage: "false",
    label: "label2",
    languages: [{
        language: "English",
        questions: [{
            choices: "choices2",
            fields: "false",
            mainText: "MAinText2",
            subText: "SubText2"
        }]
    }],
    numberOfChoices: "5"
}, {
    isnewLanguage: "true",
    label: "label1",
    languages: [{
        language: "Italian",
        questions: [{
            choices: "choicesItalian1",
            fields: "false",
            mainText: "MainTextItalian1",
            subText: "SubTextItalian1"
        }]
    }],
    numberOfChoices: "false"
}, {
    isnewLanguage: "true",
    label: "label2",
    languages: [{
        language: "Italian",
        questions: [{
            choices: "choicesItalian2",
            fields: "false",
            mainText: "MAinTextItalian2",
            subText: "SubTextItalian2"
        }]
    }],
    numberOfChoices: "false"
}, {
    isnewLanguage: "true",
    label: "label1",
    languages: [{
        language: "Chinece",
        questions: [{
            choices: "choicesChinece",
            fields: "false",
            mainText: "MainTextChinece1",
            subText: "SubTextChinece1"
        }]
    }],
    numberOfChoices: "false"
}, {
    isnewLanguage: "true",
    label: "label2",
    languages: [{
        language: "Italian",
        questions: [{
            choices: "choicesItalian2",
            fields: "false",
            mainText: "MAinTextItalian2",
            subText: "SubTextItalian2"
        }]
    }],
    numberOfChoices: "false"
}]

var byUniqueLabels = {};
var labelsArray = [];

for (var i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
    if (byUniqueLabels[test[i].label] == "" || byUniqueLabels[test[i].label] == undefined) {
        byUniqueLabels[test[i].label] = { 'isnewLanguage': test[i].isnewLanguage, 'label': test[i].label, languagesTest: [] };
    }
    for (var j = 0; j < test[i].languages.length; j++) {
        byUniqueLabels[test[i].label].languagesTest.push(test[i].languages[j]);
    }
}

for (label in byUniqueLabels) {
    labelsArray.push(byUniqueLabels[label]);
}

console.log(labelsArray);
```